# Sort iPhone TableView by Date in Filename?

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview, nsstring, sorting

The file name for my files listed in the Table View are things like:
File May 1 3:00 AM.mp3
File May 3 3:01 AM.mp3

Is there a way that I can sort it by the dates that are contained in the filenames?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Best tutorial and sample code for your question..](http://oleb.net/blog/2011/12/tutorial-how-to-sort-and-group-uitableview-by-date/)

Hope, this will you..

Comment: What I am trying to do is sort files that only have the date as part of the file name...basically extract date from the file name and then sort via date.

Comment: you can extract file name from the file and than after you can sort it..

Answer (score 0):

You have to use NSSortDescriptor :-

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

   NSSortDescriptor *sorter = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:date ascending:YES];
   [yourArrayName sortUsingDescriptors:[NSArray arrayWithObject:sorter]];

}
```

Hope it helps thanks :)

Comment: No, just no. Why are you sorting the array each time a cell is requested? That tableview is gonna lag like crazy!

Comment: What happen it does n't work??

Comment: EmilioPelaez,But the guy want to sort his table.let me give you an example:-If user create new cell at runtime then he/she will also need to sort that value.For that i have use this NSSortDescriptor in cellforrowat indexpath method

Comment: I understand what he wants to do, and what you are trying to do, but sorting an array each time a cell is requested is gonna slow down the table view. You have to sort the array first, and then return the values in that array to the table.

Comment: Yes, I don't think he deserves a downvote. The code still works and sorts and it helped me. Better place to sort would be when loading the array on view will appear or something like that still the sorting code works. He's got my up-vote for that.